# Google Maps Api without setting up a billing account

Tags: google-api, google-geocoder, api-key, billing

It's possible to use google Maps Api without a API KEY?

Using

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=[address]&sensor=false
```

I get the following error response

> REQUEST_DENIED (to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs )

I just need to do a little POC for my project.

In a other case , I create a api key and it need to enable billing.

In the process of billing ,  credit card is mandatory.

Is not possible to activate apiKey  for free?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible to use any Google api without the api key with the exception of the discovery service api i dont think that one requires it.

Depending upon the API that you are trying to use you may be required to set up a billing account. This is normally only required for apis that are not free.  An example of an api that is not free would be Maps api.

So no its not possible to use the maps api without an api key and without setting up a billing account.  It is also mandatory to have a credit card to set up a billing account this is how billing is paid for.

> Is not possible to activate apiKey for free?

yes but not and activate the Google maps api that will require a billing account.

Comment: the most infuriating part is that they won't even accept debit cards, it's credit card exclusive.. this just wrecked my whole plan..

Comment: @Ace are you sure? Because I have created billing account using debit card. But it won't work. It says The selected project and billing account cannot pay for Maps in your region. Select an existing project that is paid for by a Maps billing account.

Comment: I got the api key for my Google Map Api but I have not enabled billing still it's working fine. Can somebody explain it?